# Where is the atomic library and why is it not linking?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I'm compiling an old version of [`OGRE`](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/releases/tag/v1-9-0) ON `CMake 3.6` to see if I can compile or revive an old piece of software, and `Boost` is one of the dependencies for OGRE. It's essentially for multi-threading and without it, OGRE 1.9.0 builds completely fine on the `macOS 12.0` SDK but fails `macOS 10.8` SDK (specified in ZSH as -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET but that's another issue for later).

The CMake command: `cmake -DOGRE_CONFIG_DOUBLE=ON -DOGRE_BUILD_SAMPLES=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="x86_64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local` (yes, I'm compiling x86_64 on a arm64 machine running macOS 12.1 & XCode 13.1 if it matters)

When I build OGRE on the 12.0 SDK with Boost support (all is found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogre/files/ogre-dependencies-mac/1.9/OgreDependencies_OSX_libc%2B%2B_20130610.zip/download)), it successfully checks for all libraries. As a note, Boost also has the `atomic` library but it's only needed as `.hpp` files and not an actual `.a` or whatever-lib file format `CPP` uses. Compiling OGRE goes all well until I see this dreaded message:

```
Copying OS X content lib/macosx/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.9.0/Resources/ogrelogo.png
28 warnings generated.
21 warnings generated.
[ 44%] Linking CXX shared library ../lib/macosx/Ogre.framework/Ogre
> ld: library not found for -latomic <
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Key questions:** What *is* this `atomic` library? Is it only on an older SDK? Is it the `hpp` files? Here is the linker command shortened to where I think is the most important parts

```
cd /Users/meh/Downloads/project/ogre-1-9-0/OgreMain && /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++ -msse -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Winit-self -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wshadow -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -framework AGL -framework IOKit -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon -framework OpenGL -framework CoreVideo -compatibility_version 1.9.0 -current_version 1.9.0 -o ../lib/macosx/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.9.0/Ogre -install_name @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.9.0/Ogre (ALL THOSE OGRE .O FILES)  -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.a /usr/local/lib/Release/libFreeImage.a /usr/local/lib/Release/libzziplib.a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd -latomic
```

I had to play around with the CMake file to not error listed as:

- `framework AGL`
- `-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11`

I've done research and `atomic` shows up in `C++11` so that shouldn't be a problem? There's some include files under the SDK but definitely none under `/usr/local/lib`... (I will have to add -L/usr/local/include as a prefix to -latomic later)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989355/libatomic-is-missing-on-macos-mojave-10-14-2 might help

Comment: I don't get that warning, and I believe `OGRE` picks up the other frameworks fine, so wouldn't it error around `-framework AGL` before `-latomic`? Like I said, without `Boost`, OGRE compiles fine/.

Comment: *Actually, I should mention that OGRE compiles fine without boost because it doesn't call for the `atomic` library.